# Как сбросить учетную запись входа на сетевую папку windows 10

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10

Есть сетевая папка в домене, для неё есть два  доменных пользователя, user1 и user2 с разными полномочиями к папке. Эти пользователи работают на одной рабочей станции подключенной к доменной сети (сама станция не в домене) из под одного локального пользователя. Вход осуществляется через ярлык на рабочем столе. При первом входе  из под user1, система запросила логин и пароль. Пользователь ввел и поставил галочку "запомнить". Теперь получается, когда необходимо зайти в эту папку второму пользователю из под user2, система, запрос на логин/пароль, не выдает и получается что второй пользователь заходит постоянно из под user1.

Как сбросить учетку user1 со входа в папку на этой машине?

Как вариант - менять пароль в домене для user1, что нежелательно. Может есть варианты, чтобы не лазить на сервер?

Comment: В документации к использованию WIndows 10 должно быть написано, как управлять сохраненными паролями. Или гуглить: "find stored passwords in Windows 10"